# Does the search tracking and Amazon information sharing attributed to Ubuntu part of Debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, search, gnu, defaults

I understand from [Richard Stallman in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXnfa0H30L4), made probably in 2012/2013, that Ubuntu isn't 100% free by the GNU organization definition of Free Software, as according to Stallman there, it "spies" on users and also share the "spied" information with Amazon.

I asked about it in AskUbuntu but my question was putted off topic and heavily disliked so I removed it.

I'm not sure if the mechanisms Stallman mentiones (without even knowing how accurate he was) still exist in Ubuntu in 2018, but do they exist in Debian?

Do Debian desktop has such things?

I don't mind install **some** third party software on Debian desktop (like Nvidia software) but I would still like to know of the aforementioned mechanisms (by Stallman), or even similar tracking mechanisms exist in Debian.

I ask this question as I stronly contemplate to move to a new OS and I'm very much into Debian systems, from various reasons.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/565746/why-does-the-latest-build-of-ubuntu-have-an-amazon-button

Comment: No, the Debian project would never do such a thing.

Comment: A new feature will be available on Ubuntu 18.04 : [Ubuntu Wants to Collect Data About Your System](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/02/ubuntu-data-collection-opt-out)

Comment: @GAD3R I didn't understand if the author is happy from this or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a feature provided by Unity’s shopping lens; it [was removed in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192269/how-can-i-remove-amazon-search-results-from-the-dash-or-disable-the-feature), and was never available in Debian.